# Is there any way to set Windows Phone Settings (like screen brightness) programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way to set any of settings from "Settings menu" programmatically, from app?

For example change date-time, set screen brightness or change theme color, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment this functionality is not exposed by the API.

Only the user can control these features.

Comment: What about workarounds or something like that? Nothing can be done?

Comment: It's been made fairly clear that attempts to circumvent the platform will result in certification failure for apps. There's been little discussion on it, other than to note that presence of any native code, p/invokes or dynamically loaded code (which might be capable of such) will result in a cert fail.

Comment: @MickN what about for my own use. I want a brightness control on my homescreen that toggles brightness between levels. if this can be p/invoked that would be just fine for my own personal use